# NetCore - Resolve internal dependencies

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-core

I'm creating a project soon to be a nuget. There is a public class where I inject a class whose visibility modifier is `internal`, but the compiler states:

> Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'blah' is less accessible than method 'bleh'

I don't want to expose the rest of the project classes to the rest of the world. Is it possible to do?

[image]

AuthenticationContext resolution:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject `IServiceProvider` and get your service like

```
 var authContext = _serviceProvider.GetService<AuthenticationContext>();
```

or you need to change accessibility of your method

Comment: According to this post: https://andrewlock.net/the-difference-between-getservice-and-getrquiredservice-in-asp-net-core/ using serviceProvider would be an anti-pattern, but I see no other solution so far.